# telebot не определяет Inlinekeyboard

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, cmd, telebot

Создаю в телеге бота, первый проект не судите строго.
Не могу ввести inlinekeyboard, Почему то телебот не видит его и консоль пишет, что модуль не имеет inlinekeyboard.
Запускаю через cmd и pythonanywhere и там и там одинаковая ошибка

Код:

`````
  ```` import telebot
      import config
      from telebot import types 
       bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
       @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
      def welcome(message):
           #keyboard
          markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True) 
          item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Понедельник")
          item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Вторник")
          item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Среда")
          item4 = types.KeyboardButton("Четверг")
          item5 = types.KeyboardButton("Пятница")
          item6 = types.KeyboardButton("Суббота")
          item7 = types.KeyboardButton("Перемены")
          item8 = types.KeyboardButton("Сведение")
      markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Салам, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, 
      бот созданный ,чтобы был.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
         parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
   @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def lalala(message):
     if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Понедельник':
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Вторник':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Среда':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'ОРЭГ \nФизра \nСтатистика')
        if message.text == 'Четверг':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'Программирование \nБух.учёт \nИРиВС')
        if message.text == 'Пятница':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'Инструментальные средства \nКомпьютерная 
        графика \nФизра')
        if message.text == 'Суббота':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Пока неизвестно')
        if message.text == 'Перемены':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,u'1 пара 8:00-9:20 \n2 пара 9:30-10:50 \n3 пара 
        11:00-12:20 \n4 пара 12:40-14:00')
            elif message.text == 'Сведение':
        #inline keyboard
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardsMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Список" ,callback_data='good')
             item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Данные" ,callback_data='bad')
               bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Что именно интересует?', reply_markup=markup)
             markup.add(item1, item2)            
 @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
 def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'информация')
           elif call.data == 'bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'информация')    
            # remove inline buttons
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, 
message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Сведение",
               reply_markup=None)
           # show alert
           bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                text="ЗАПРОС ВЫПОЛНЕН!!"))              
   except Exception as e:
       print(repr(e))
 # RUN
 bot.polling(none_stop=True)
`````

```
Выводит ошибку :
 markup = types.InlineKeyboardsMarkup(row_width=2)
AttributeError: module 'telebot.types' has no attribute 'InlineKeyboardsMarkup'
>>> 
Помогите пожалуйcта 
пробовал удалять телебот и заново скачивать и обновлял pip
```

Comment: Функция называется **`InlineKeyboardMarkup`**, а вы пишите *`InlineKeyboardsMarkup`*

Comment: `if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if if ` не надо так писать, есть циклы!